# Unknown System Error -8 Puppeteer Core and Chromium JS

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I'm using puppeteer-core (v19.4) and @sparticuz/chromium (v109.0.5) for an aws lambda project. For the past month it's been working beautifully. However, recently I've been getting this error in my serverless console:

```
{
  errno: -8,
  code: 'Unknown system error -8',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
{
    "errorMessage": "No browser!",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Error: No browser!",
```

This is the code I use to set up puppeteer and chromium in my project.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");

( async () => { try {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
    headless: chromium.headless,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.google.com", { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

  console.log("Chromium:", await browser.version());
  console.log("Page Title:", await page.title());

  await page.close();

  await browser.close();
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error(error.message);
}})();
```

When I run the above code by itself, outside the context of my project, I get this error.

`Error: spawn Unknown system error -8`

I get the same error with puppeteer-core v21.3 and @sparticuz/chromium v117.0.0